# team setup and deploying for a laravel production evironment

Tags: git, laravel-5, web-deployment, production-environment, continuous-deployment

I am just starting own as a developer. I am currently working with laravel and soon Nodejs. I have a very small budget so free and open source are my best friends. i have two questions.

1. how do i setup my team to work with git so that every can be working on something related to the same project without having much conflict with access management?
2. how do i setup my production environment, in term of deployment and roll back with minimum or no downtime? currently i am using filezilla but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of options!

Best of all, they're all free if your own project is also open-source.
This means your repo needs to be public.
If you need a private repo, fear not - the fees are minimal and these steps can still be followed within a reasonably tight budget.

1. Create a repo and host your source code on github (or bitbucket, or gitlab, or whatever - but github is very widely supported)
2. Figure out how you are going to build your laravel project, and script it. It may be as simple as npm run dev, npm run production, etc.
3. Setup an account on AppVeyor and/or TravisCI. Use Appveyor if you want to run the build on windows machines, run on travisCi if you want to run the build on linux/macOS machines. You can also look into VSTS, but that will cost a bit more than these options.
4. Learn maven or gradle or some other build tool you can use. maven and gradle have ways to deploy to production. this will all be scripted and configured within the build tool itself.
5. Configure appveyor/travisci/vsts to run a maven/gradle build on your project.

Best part about appveyor/travisCI is that these are entirely free for open source projects - meaning, your builds will run on someone else's hardware and electric bill. How's that for keeping costs low?
Finally, you'll want to roll out to production - again, maven and gradle have built in configurations for handling this.

Steps 4 and 5 will be the hardest for a newbie, but it's not tough to learn - just takes some time :)

p.s. jenkins is a fine build system as well, but it will cost you a pretty penny to use - same with VSTS. **The recommendations I made for you above are best for saving cost.** They are also some of the most popular, if not the most popular, tools to use for open-source (read: free) development projects

None of this is easy, especially if you've never touched maven or gradle before, or had any experience with CI/CD (continuous integration/continuous deployment). But CI/CD practices are everywhere in software development, and there are plenty of resources out there on the web to help you along!

best of luck to you!

Comment: ok thanks will take a look at those. i have worked with bitbucket but not from a team perspective